# Counting uppercase and lowercase characters of String and appending count to the character

Tags: java, run-length-encoding

I am trying to print the output of a String to find the count of uppercase and lowercase in it.

E.g. if string = "AaaBBbCc",
I need the output as : "A1a2B2b1C1c1".

I.E. count of uppercase 'A' then count of lowercase 'a', appending with the characters.

Below is the code snippet till where I have done. Can any one suggest how it goes.
I know code is not up-to the mark :(

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String str = "AaaBBbCc";
    int upperCount=0;
    int lowerCount=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        char ch = str.charAt(i);
        if(ch>='A' && ch<='Z'){
             upperCount++;
             System.out.println("Uppercase letter is : "+ch+upperCount);

    }
     if(ch>='a' && ch<='z'){
        lowerCount++;
        System.out.println("Lower case letter is : "+ch+lowerCount);
    }
}
    System.out.println("upper count is :"+upperCount+" & lower count is: "+lowerCount);
```

}

Comment: Are all of the equal letters always next to each other, like in your example? Will there ever be non-letter characters in the string?

Comment: [`if (Character.isUpperCase(ch))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) / [`if (Character.isLowerCase(ch))`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLowerCase%28char%29)

Comment: @AndyTurner Ah, OK, I looked more closely at the code and skipped the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish here is called [Run-length encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding). This is sometimes referred to as a form of lossless data compression in which the length of a continuous character is appended to a single instance of that character. Here is a modified version from [RosettaCode](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding#Java) that should do the trick for you:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class RunLengthEncoding {

    public static String encode(String source) {
        StringBuffer dest = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < source.length(); i++) {
            int runLength = 1;
            while (i+1 < source.length() && source.charAt(i) == source.charAt(i+1)) {
                runLength++;
                i++;
            }
            /* We will swap these so they fit your format of [Letter][Count]
            dest.append(runLength);
            dest.append(source.charAt(i));
            */
            dest.append(source.charAt(i));
            dest.append(runLength);
        }
        return dest.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String example = "WWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWBBBWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWWBWWWWWWWWWWWWWW";
        System.out.println(encode(example));
    }
}
```

Comment: What will happen if the input string is "AaBBAAAaCac" ??
I think the ans should be A4a3B2C1c1, isn't it?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna Original question seems a bit unclear as to whether they want just the count of all uppercase and lowercase letters (Because of `System.out.println("upper count is :"+upperCount+" & lower count is: "+lowerCount);`), something exactly like run-length encoding (Because of "E.g. if string = "AaaBBbCc", I need the output as : "A1a2B2b1C1c1"."), or something along the lines of what you said where the output is alphabetized with each character count appearing after the letter (From what you said).

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track. If you want to count which letters appear, not only if they are upper or lower case, you could create 2 `int[]` arrays `upperCaseCount` and `lowerCaseCount = new int[26]`. You could use these arrays to keep count of which letters are appearing.

**Hint** you can exploit the fact that `char` can be used as `int` to determine which index you should increment:

```
int index = ? //'a' should be 0 for lower, and 'A' should be 0 for upper
lowerCaseCount[index]++ or upperCaseCount[index]++;
```